Treat Variables as single entities for deletion in a Text Box Using JavaScript
I have a text box field in my simple HTML/JavaScript-based form where users can insert variables, as shown in the example below:
The name of the product is ${productName}

When the user submits the form, a JavaScript function replaces the variable with its actual product value.
I’d like to implement a feature where, if the user places their cursor to the right of the variable ${productName} and presses the backspace key, the entire variable is deleted in one go, instead of deleting each character one at a time. Placing the cursor in the middle of variable text should not do anything. User shouldnt be allowed to delete individual character of the variable and/or add characters. Essentially, I want the variable to behave as a single, indivisible entity in the text box.
I’m unsure what the technical term for this feature is or how to start researching it. What’s the most efficient way to implement this behaviour?

@trincot updated the question.

Here is an attempt to implement the rules:

If text is selected, and it overlaps a token, then no modification can be made.
If no text is selected, but the caret sits inside a token, then no modification can be made.
If no text is selected, and the caret is right after a token, then a backspace will delete that token.
If no text is selected, and the caret is right before a token, then a delete key will delete that token.
In all other cases, keys will act normally.

This code does not itself mutate the value. It merely changes the selection of the text upon which the key will act. That way the undo/redo mechanism will continue to work as expected.
This implementation also listens to the beforeinput event to also prevent non-allowed changes being made via other input methods (such as drag/drop, context menu).


function getNextToken(s, i) {
    const match = /\$\{[^{}]*}/d.exec(s.slice(i));
    return match?.indices[0].map(k => k + i);
}

function getNearTokens(input) {
    const {selectionStart: i, selectionEnd: j, value} = input;
    // Get the offsets of nearby ${...} occurences
    const left = getNextToken(value, value.lastIndexOf("${", i - 1));
    const right = getNextToken(value, value.lastIndexOf("${", j));
    return {
        // Check if the current caret (selection) overlaps a token
        overlaps: left?.[0] < i && i < left?.[1] || right?.[0] < j && j < right?.[1],
        // Check if the caret is adjacent to token(s) -- without any text selected
        adjacentLeft: i === j && left?.[1] === i && left,
        adjacentRight: i === j && right?.[0] === j && right
    };
}

const input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    // Only interested in these two keys
    if (!["Backspace","Delete"].includes(e.key)) return;
    const {adjacentLeft, adjacentRight} = getNearTokens(e.target);
    // If there is no selection, and a deletion would enter a token,
    //   then first select that whole token, so the upcoming deletion will affect all of it
    if (e.key === "Backspace" && adjacentLeft) {
        input.selectionStart = adjacentLeft[0];
    } else if (e.key === "Delete" && adjacentRight) {
        input.selectionEnd = adjacentRight[1];
    }
});

input.addEventListener("beforeinput", function (e) {
    // If selection starts or ends within a token, abort the upcoming modification.
    if (getNearTokens(e.target).overlaps) e.preventDefault();
});
<input size="100%" value="Hello ${beautiful} world! The population is ${population}.">



